# pure function inside of main not taking & processing individual values of x the way I intended

Tags: c, function, for-loop, parameter-passing, pure-virtual

- Write a pure function inside of main() that computes Normal Distribution equation.
- Ask users for 2 variables that remain constant in the formula
- Ask the user for N values of x whose value needs to change every time I send it into the function.
- For each different x, its prints out "F(x) = " + the result from the calculation.

I have already tried pointing to the variable x and declaring it within the for loop, I believe it is a problem with my scope or declaration of the function in general. I dont understand why my professor is asking us to declare the function in main() when in every other programming language I have worked with it has been done outside. I believe he is trying to teach us something about scope but so far it has just messed with my sense of what is wrong and what is right. Any Help would be appreciated I've been toying with this thing for hours! Sincerely, JJC

```
int main(void)
{
    const double sigma, mu;
    double  x;

    int no_x;

    double normal(x, sigma, mu)
    {   
        return (x * sigma * mu);
    }

    printf("Enter mean u: ");   
    scanf("%lf", &mu);

    printf("Enter standard deviation: ");   
    scanf("%lf", &sigma);

    if(sigma == 0)
    {
        printf("error you entered: 0");
        exit(0);
    }

    printf("Number of x values: "); 
    scanf("%d", &no_x);

    for(int i = 1; i <= no_x; i++)
    {
        printf("x value %d : ", i);

        scanf("%lf", &x);

        printf("f(x) = : ");
        normal(x,sigma,mu);

        printf("");
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Expected Results

```
C:\>.\a.exe
Enter mean u: 3.489
Enter std dev s: 1.203
Number of x values: 3
x value 1: 3.4
f(X) = 0.330716549275
x value 2: -3.4
f(X) = 0.000000025104
x value 3: 4
f(X) = 0.303015189801
```

Comment: Start by putting the function outside of `main`. And then compile with `-Wall`, read the warnings, and fix the warnings. Once the code compiles cleanly, you can move the function inside of `main`. Note that nested functions are not allowed by the C standard, but are allowed by some compilers. So I'm puzzled as to why the professor is telling you to do this.

Comment: Also note that if you don't specify a type for a function argument, the type defaults to `int`. That's not what you want for the `normal` function.

Comment: thank you i got it to compile and  the function call working properly with the loop. I am just having trouble with the function outputting the proper results now so I am going to create a separate thread on that. Thank you for the help

Answer (score 0):

You're discarding the return of `normal`

Try:

```
x = normal(x,sigma,mu);
```

and/or pass the return to a call to `printf` (with the appropriate format)